# Why the same files are copied to /Approot and /Siteroot in Windows Azure WebRole?

Tags: iis, deployment, azure, azure-web-roles

I found that approot and sitesroot are used for:

> \Approot - The customer’s code, aspx pages, DLLs, etc.
>   \Sitesroot\ – This is the folder where the full IIS site is run
>   from.  When the role is deployed, the files from \Approot are copied
>   to this \Sitesroot folder and then IIS will be configured to run the
>   site from \Sitesroot.  Any temporary test changes to the role
>   (web.config changes, new DLLs, etc) should be placed here.

I wonder why there are two sparate folders as they contain the same files?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11897132/57428 - that's how the defaults work, you can easily get rid of that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `AppRoot` is used at role startup and shoud contain one derived class from [`RoleEntryPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleentrypoint.aspx). This content is from web role configured site and is used by `WaIISHost` worker process.
- `SiteRoot` contains web sites from node [`Sites`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg557553.aspx#Sites) in the `.csdef` file and are configured in IIS.

Comment: I was wondering how I can manage to deploy a folder/files only in sitesroot, because at the moment I have my approot bloated.