# How to manually update an Azure webrole when all you have is RDP access

Tags: deployment, azure

I'm sure many might know of the Azure outage right now. I'm trying to update our Cloud services website (webrole) but almost every avenue seems to be dependent on azure storage (VS2012, TFS continuous deployment or portal upgrade). At least I think so because they all are failing right now.

I can still RDP into each role and since I have 4, it might be doable (but not enjoyable). Once I RDP, I see

`e:\approot` and `e:\sitesroot\0\`

I fired up task manager, killed w3wp.exe's and WaIISHost.exe's (MVC4 app's .dll was in use) and replaced the files there and then rebooted the role. The changes aren't being reflected after rebooting.

Any ideas how to update when RDP is all you have (and mount the developer's drive as a local resource to copy files back and forth) ?

Comment: Actually overwriting `e:\sitesroot\0\` does seem to work. I think I was hitting the wrong server behind the load balancer before. I don't think these changes are durable (eg role gets recycled), so lets see ..

Comment: You're right, those changes won't stick forever, but they should be enough to get you through the current problems.

Comment: I'd guess the service package (or the part with the role payload) is stored on the VM somewhere and when the reboot is done it is unpacked again and so your changes are lost.

Comment: Right, any changes done using RDP are not persisted across reboots. We have done this number of times and all changes are lost, in case Role restart upgrade etc.

Comment: Btw you might have noticed that `approot` and `sitesroot\0` contain the same stuff and that inflates the package and increases packing time. Here's now you can get rid of this http://stackoverflow.com/q/11897132/57428

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself, but I've heard from someone at Microsoft that if you use the management API directly (or possibly through the [Azure powershell cmdlets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj883943.aspx#BKMK_update_service)) you're able to make changes.  It's worth noting that as part of this outage (2013-02-23) you can still use http to access storage, just not https, so if while using the API it needs a reference to storage (which I'm pretty sure doing a new deployment does) just make sure you don't use https.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the solution that worked well for us is:

- Download the .RDP file from the azure portal (select instance => connect)
- Edit the .rdp file => local resource tab => more => drives => c: (or wherever your local build lives)
- RDP into the machine
- Within Windows explorer, copy build files from the local machine (mounted as a network drive over RDP) over to `e:\sitesroot\0\` (sometimes `f:`)
- restart IIS via IIS Manager (sometimes needed)
- hope that your role doesn't get recycled!

It's not a permanent solution but works well during moments of limited availability.