# How is staying my deployment in Azure machines?

Tags: azure

I have a question about Remote Desktop deployment on Azure Cloud Application.

First of all I published my app via visual studio.Everything is working.

Yesterday I connected with remote desktop to my azure app and changed some attributes in my web.config files.

First thing : My cloud app is getting so slowly so I think IIS restart etc. but I don't know why my site is coming slowly ?

Second thing : Today when I enter to my app , I can't see my changes and when I check it via remote desktop all my changed things are roll back. Why ?

Do I have to all my deployment via Visual Studio ?

How is staying my deployment in Azure machines ? This machine is sometimes changing or never change when I delete it ?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you make your changes in the approot folder or in the webroot folder?

Comment: @danludwig: Here's how to get away with just one folder most of the times http://stackoverflow.com/q/11897132/57428

Comment: @danludwig If I change my things in approot and webroot, will my changes persist ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the expected way to change the settings. Azure is free to relocate your instance to another VM or restart it in-place and erase all your local changes.

So if you want to do some permanent changes you have to do them locally, build the service package and deploy the new package to Azure. This way Azure will have an updated package and your changes will persist.

If you want to change something frequently you have to use the `<ConfigurationSettings>` node of the service configuration. Your code will have to query the setting and react accordingly. If you want some activity triggered when the service configuration is changed your code has to handle the `RoleEnvironment.Changing` event.

Comment: Thanks for second question.I learnt ;) 
What do u thing my first question ?                                 - I connected with remote desktop to my azure app and changed some attributes in my web.config files.

My cloud app is getting so slowly so I think IIS restart etc. but I don't know why my site is coming slowly ?

Comment: @SerkanYılmaz: Can be anything, no way to tell without profiling.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make changes in the VM directly, because these changes are not persisted (as you have already noticed). The VM can be recycled and restored at any moment. So you have to make changes by applying them locally and redeploy the site.